# 500 internal server error , express react mongo mern stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express

hi I'm having trouble with the signup form in my react component, I use mongodb and here is my server, route and signup component
i get this error

```js
xhr.js:178 POST http://localhost:3000/api/user/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:178
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:12
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:59
Promise resolved (async)
request @ Axios.js:51
Axios.(anonymous function) @ Axios.js:71
wrap @ bind.js:9
saveUser @ API.js:18
Signup._this.handleSubmit @ Signup.js:47
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:540
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:579
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:436
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:450
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:834
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:853
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js:954
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:965
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js:933
processEventQueue @ react-dom.development.js:1105
runEventQueueInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:3600
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:3609
handleTopLevelImpl @ react-dom.development.js:3340
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:11066
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2323
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:3414
API.js:20 Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
xhr.js:178 XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost:3000/api/user/".
```

I don't know if I'm connected to the datatbase , eventhough the mongo client is working.

server.js

```js
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const routes = require("./routes");
const app = express();
const User = require("./models/users");
//authentication packages
const session = require('express-session');
const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

// Configure body parser for AJAX requests
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//set up cookies for sessions
app.use(cookieParser());

// Serve up static assets (usually on heroku)
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static("client/build"));
}

// Add routes, both API and view
app.use(routes);

// Set up promises with mongoose
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

// Connect to the Mongo DB
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost/airlane", {useMongoClient: true});

//initialize passport and express-session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'holla hoops', //random key
    store: new MongoStore({ url: MONGODB_URI }),
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


//setting passport for log in, log out and signup
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
  db.User.findOne({ _id: user.userID }).then((user, error) => {
    if (error) {
      done(error);
    }

    done(null, user);
  });
});

passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      usernameField: "email" //change default username to email
    },
    (email, password, done) => {
      console.log(email);
      console.log(password);
      // return done(null, "LOGIN SUCCESSFUL!");

      db.User.findOne({ email }).then((user, error) => {
        if (error) {
          done(error);
        }

        const hashPass = user.password;

        console.log("Hash: " + hashPass);

        if (hashPass.length === 0) {
          //essentially, if no user info is returned
          done(null, false);
        } else {
          //... else, run the bycrypt compare method to authenticate

          //bcrypt de-hash
          bcrypt.compare(password, hashPass, (err, response) => {
            if (response === true) {
              console.log("Successful login!");
              return done(null, { userID: user._id });
            } else {
              console.log("Unsuccessful login!");
              return done(null, false);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  )
);

// Send every request to the React app
// Define any API routes before this runs
app.get("*", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/build/index.html"));
});

app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log(` ==> Server now on port ${PORT}!`);
});


userController.js
```

```js
const db = require("../models");
const path = require("path");


//methods to connect to mongo db
module.exports  = {
    findAll: function(req, res) {
        db
        .find(console.log(res))
        .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
        .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
    },
    findById: function(req, res) {
        db
        .findById(req.params.id)
        .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
        .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
    },
    create: function(req, res) {
        console.log("Running create: ");
        db
        .create(req.body)
        .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
        .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
    },
    update: function(req, res) {
        db
        .findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, dbModel)
        .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
        .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));;
    },
    remove: function(req, res) {
        db
        .findById({ _id: req.params.id })
        .then(function(dbModel) { dbModel.remove();})
        .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
        .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
    }

};


// // Dependencies
// // =============================================================
// const passport = require('passport');
// const db = require("../models");
// const path = require("path");
// const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
// const session = require('express-session');
// const authenticationMiddleware = require('../utils/authenticationMiddleware');
// const saltRounds = 10;

// // Routes
// // =============================================================
// module.exports = (app) => {

//     // send basic index.html file at root
//     app.get("/", (req, res) => {

//         //console log user info if any
//         console.log(req.user);
//         console.log(req.isAuthenticated());

//         res.send("../public/index.html")

//     });

//     // register new user
//     app.post("/register", (req, res) => {

//         const email = req.body.email;
//         const password = req.body.password;

//         bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, (err, hash) => {

//             const newUser = {
//                 email,
//                 password: hash
//             };

//             db.User
//                 .create(newUser)
//                 .then((user) => {

//                     //console.log(user);
//                     console.log("This is the userID for new user:");
//                     console.log(user._id);

//                     db.User
//                         .findOne({ _id: user._id })
//                         .then((signedInUser, error) => {

//                             if (error) throw (error);

//                             console.log("NEW USER CREATED: ");
//                             console.log(signedInUser);
//                             //deserialize config is expecting user.userID to be accessible
//                             req.login({userID: signedInUser._id}, (err) => {

//                                 res.redirect("/");

//                             })

//                         })

//                 })
//                 .catch((err) => {
//                     // If an error occurred, send it to the client
//                     console.log(err);
//                     res.redirect("/");
//                 });
//         });

//     });

//     app.post("/login", passport.authenticate('local', {

//         successRedirect: "/profile", //if login was successful, redirect to profile page
//         failureRedirect: "/" //if login unseccussful, redirect to homepage

//     }), );

//     app.post("/logout", (req, res) => {

//         console.log(`Logging out user:`);
//         console.log(req.user);

//         req.session.destroy( (err) => {
//             req.logout();
//             res.send(true);
//         })

//     });

//     // profile page. Only renders if authentication is verified, if not, redirect to root 
//     app.get("/profile", authenticationMiddleware(), (req, res) => {

//         //console log user info if any
//         console.log(req.user);
//         console.log(req.isAuthenticated());

//         res.redirect("/")

//     });


// };
```

Axios Api.js

```js
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  // Gets all user
  getUsers: () => {
    return axios.get("/api/user");
  },
  // Gets the user with the given id
  getUser: (id) => {
    return axios.get("/api/user/" + id);
  },
  // Deletes the user with the given id
  deleteUser: (id) => {
    return axios.delete("/api/user/" + id);
  },
  // Saves a user to the database
  saveUser: (userData) => {
    return axios.post("/api/user/", userData)
                .then(console.log(userData))
                .catch(err =>{console.log(err)})
  }
};
```

react signup component

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Button,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  ControlLabel,
  Modal
} from "react-bootstrap";
import API from "../Utils/API";


class Signup extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: false,
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      email: "",
      password: "",
      passwordConf: "",
      userCreated: Date
    };
    this.open = this.open.bind(this);
    this.close = this.close.bind(this);
  }

  open = () => {
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  };

  close = () => {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  };

  // Handles updating component state when the user types into the input field
  handleChange = event => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  //when the form is submitted, use the API to save a user
  handleSubmit = () => {
    API.saveUser({ 
        firstName: this.state.firstName,
        lastName: this.state.lastName,
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password,
        userCreated: Date.now
       })
      .then(console.log(this.state))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };

  render() {
    return <div>
        <div onClick={this.open}>Sign Up</div>
        <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
          <Modal.Header closeButton>
            <Modal.Title>Registeration</Modal.Title>
          </Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body>
            <div>
              <form >
                <FormGroup>
                  <ControlLabel htmlFor="firstName">
                    First Name
                  </ControlLabel>
                  <FormControl name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="ex: Michael" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                  <ControlLabel htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</ControlLabel>
                  <FormControl name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="ex: Smith" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                  <ControlLabel htmlFor="email">Eamil</ControlLabel>
                  <FormControl name="email" type="email" placeholder="ex: johnSmith@email.com" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                  <ControlLabel htmlFor="password">Password</ControlLabel>
                  <FormControl name="password" type="password" placeholder="New Password!" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup>
                  <ControlLabel htmlFor="passwordconf">
                    Confrim Password
                  </ControlLabel>
                  <FormControl name="passwordConf" type="password" placeholder="confirm new password" onChange={this.handleChange} />
                </FormGroup>
                <Button type="submit" value="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
                  Submit
                </Button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <div>
              <Button>Facebook</Button>
              <Button>Google</Button>
            </div>
            <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
      </div>;
  }
}

export default Signup;
```

it keeps giving me 500 internal server error

Comment: What the response of the request?

Comment: But.. What prints to the console? What the error message?

Comment: Please put it formatted in your question

Comment: it has somthing to do with the api not connecting to mongodb i just can't figure out where the break is , and i'm so sorry @Michael this is my very first stackoverflow question ever

Comment: It's ok just be sure to read:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and similar posts. Are you sure you are not missing a port here: "mongodb://localhost/airlane"? try: "mongodb://localhost:27017/airlane"